# topic is already advertised as md5sum [...] and datatype [...]

Tags: rosout, libroscpp, publisher, logging, logger

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get output from a remote node to the /rosout topic and view it with 'rostopic echo rosout' running on the master. I have a roscore running on hostA brought up by starting roslaunch. On hostB, I have a node built from roscpp.

My nodes code is as follows:

```
int func1()
{
    if (ros::console::set_logger_level(ROSCONSOLE_DEFAULT_NAME,
        ros::console::levels::Debug) ) {
            ros::console::notifyLoggerLevelsChanged();
        }

    map<string, string> remap;
    remap.emplace("__ip", get_ip());
    remap.emplace("__master", get_master_uri());

    ros::init(remap, "test-node");
    ros::Time::init();

    while (!ros::master::check()) {
        ros::Duration(1.0).sleep();
    }

    nh = boost::make_shared<ros::NodeHandle>();

    ros::spinOnce();

    return 0;
}

int func2()
{
    ROS_INFO("point A");

    ros::Publisher pub =
        nh->advertise<std_msgs::String>("rosout", 1000);

    ROS_INFO("point B");

    std_msgs::String msg;
    stringstream ss;
    ss << "Using stringstream.";
    msg.data = ss.str();
    pub.publish(msg);

    ROS_INFO("point C"); 
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("ss data: " << msg.data);

    ROS_INFO_STREAM("ROS Node Namespace: " << ros::this_node::getNamespace());
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("ROS Node Name: " << ros::this_node::getName());

    ROS_INFO("point 4");

    return 0;    
}
```

The only thing I ever see show up on the master node is "point A", "point B" never prints and I get the following message on the master node.

```
Tried to advertise on topic [/rosout] with md5sum [992ce8a1687cec8c8bd883ec973ca4131] and datatype [std_msgs/String], but the topic is already advertised as md5sum [acffd30cd6b6de30f120938c17c593fb] and datatype [rosgraph_msgs/Log]
```

No where's have I used a datatype of rosgraph_msgs and I'm not sure why the message says so. rqt_console shows me the message is coming from the node "test-node" as an error. Sometimes the "point A" message will come through with severity 'Info' and shows up properly, but won't go beyond the error above.

Also, how is it that ROS_INFO("point A") shows up on the /rosout of the master, yet the topic hasn't even been advertised yet?

Thoughts?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258657/topic-is-already-advertised-as-md5sum-%5B...%5D-and-datatype-%5B...%5D/) by [SRD](https://answers.ros.org/users/27821/srd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-04-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `rosout` topic is advertised by `ros::init` as part of the node setup; you don't need to advertise on it yourself.

In addition, ROS_INFO and the associated logging macros already handle publishing to `rosout`.

The publisher you've created conflicts with the default publisher, which is why you're getting this error message.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1